# Xcode Cloud API. How can I create or update environment variables in a workflow using the API?

Tags: xcode-cloud

I have been assigned a task to automate the process of updating environment variables for a workflow in Xcode Cloud.

After reviewing the **API** documentation, I discovered an object that can update a workflow, which is the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/ciworkflowupdaterequest.
However, it seems that this object does not provide a way to update environment variables.

Please advise me on how to find an appropriate method to update the environment variables automatically.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/ciworkflowcreaterequest/data/attributes

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/ciworkflowupdaterequest

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, there unfortunately is no existing public API that would allow this nor any other known workaround but to update them manually by editing the workflow in the App Store Connect web form.